# Path to string in java files

Tags: java

In my program I have a .txt file that has some config values in it.

I have my config.txt laid out like this:

```
Users:
  Jeff: 14
  Jimmy: 23
  Jack: 532
```

I have code that consists of a scanner, a few variables, and a few printline commands.

I want the user of the program to enter a name, and if the name they enter exists in the config, to return the value, and if the name doesn't exist, add the name to a list and assign it a value.

I know how to create and read and write to files, but how do I write and read under the "Users:" key?

I've done a good bit of research but I haven't been able to figure it out.

EDIT:
I've been messing with some code, and I got this.

```
      //Code used to get the username to read.
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      String user = new String();
      String pass = new String();

      //Username Detection
      System.out.println("Please enter your username.");
      user = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("User name is: "+user);
      try {
        readSSDB(user);
        
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Do something with `e`
      }
```

```
    //Code used to check the file.
    public static void readSSDB(String user) throws FileNotFoundException{
      File SSDB = new File("SSDB.txt");

      System.out.println("File Reader Loaded Successfully.");

      Scanner read = new Scanner(SSDB);

      String userRead = read.nextLine();

      boolean userFound = false;

      while(userFound == false){
        if(read.nextLine().contains(user)){
          
          System.out.println("Found user: "+userFound);
        }else{
          System.out.println("No user '"+user+"' found!");
          read.nextLine();
        }
      }
    }
```

EDIT 2: Realized I said while(userFound = false) instead of while(userFound == false).

Output I get is: "No user 'Jimmy' found! Found instead: 'Jimmy: 23'"

Shouldn't `if(read.nextLine().contains(user)){` return true because read.nextLine() is "Jimmy: 23" and user is "Jimmy" so logically speaking "Jimmy: 23" does contain "Jimmy"?

Answer (score 0):

You can read file using `nextLine()` and

```java
if(scannedLine.contains(name)) {
    //return data to the user
} else {
    //add user to he config file
}
```

Have you tried something like this?

Comment: I have not, I'll mess with it and see if I can get it to work, Thanks!